# How to overwrite content in a 7z archive created from a pipe?

Tags: 7z

## Purpose

I'm creating a function that dumps a database table to a compressed `7z` file. The output of `mysqldump` is piped to `7zr` with the `-si` switch. There should always be one file and one file only in the resulting `7z` file. The resulting file has a name such as `database_table.sql.7z`. If my function is called and the archive exists already, it does not recreate the archive, unless `force=TRUE`. If `force=TRUE`, it deletes the archive `rm database.sql.7z` and compresses it again. Is there a way to implement this file removal with `rm` and archive compression again with a 7zr switch?

As I wrote above, the output of `mysqldump` is piped to `7zr` with the `-si` switch so that there is no file "File on Disk" to compare with the "File in Archive" as explained in the  `-u` [update switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm) documentation.

## Issue

My issue is that if the archive file already exists, the content is added to the existing archive instead of overwriting all archive content. For example if I create a dummy archive with:

```
 $ echo "Hello"| 7zr a -si hello.txt.7z
Creating archive hello.txt.7z

Compressing  [Content]      

Everything is Ok
```

I can run the command a second time:

```
 $ echo "Hello"| 7zr a -si hello.txt.7z
Updating archive hello.txt.7z

Compressing  [Content]      

Everything is Ok
```

But the third time 7zr returns an error:

```
 $ echo "Hello"| 7zr a -si hello.txt.7z

Error:
Duplicate filename:
hello.txt
hello.txt
```

My fall back solution is to simply delete the archive before recreating it.
In fact I would like to overwrite the archive content, but the overwrite switch `-ao` only works for extraction, not for creating an archive. Which [7zr switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/) can I use for that purpose?

Comment: Does my (edited) answer help? It took me longer than it should have to figure out what you were asking but I think I got it now.

Comment: Yes thanks passing a file name to the standard input option fixes it: `echo "Hello"| 7zr a -sihello.txt hello.txt.7z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Overwrite' is a bit vague but let's say you want to update an existing archive so it's in sync with changes from the directory that the archive was originally created from. Use the `u` switch then figure out the magic code from the third table on this page https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm

If I created the archive from a directory *foo* like this:

```
7zr a foo.7z foo
```

Then I can bring file additions, changes or deletions ('synchronize') to *foo* with this:

```
7zr u foo.7z -up1q0r2y2 foo
```

The magic code may differ slightly depending on what changes you're interested in (see the first table on that page).

Pretty arcane.

**Edit:** After some back and forth it seems that OP requires that the archive be populated from STDIN and simply wants to overwrite existing archive contents each time. The following addresses that.

You need to to specify a "filename" that will be associated with your data. This is done by putting a name after the `-si` flag (with no space between):

```
<input> | 7zr a -sifoo foo.7z
```

This command works for initial creation of the archive as well as updating.

Background: as seen here https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/stdin.htm

> If file_name is not specified, data will be stored without a name

So 7zr won't have any way to know that existing contents are associated with subsequent input. That's why you see a new archive entry every time you update. Once you give your input a name, 7zr knows that you are trying to update what's already there.

Comment: For information, I'm implementing this compression as part of a function that performs a SQL dump, there is only one file in the .7z archive. Thank you for the link, I have been puzzled by this [update switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm) for a couple of hours, that's why I asked the question. If overwrite is vague, let's say that if the archive exists, I simply want to remove the file with `rm hello.txt.7z`. Is there a switch that would simply perform this?

Comment: @PaulRougieux You want to remove the archive itself? That's what this is: `rm hello.txt.7z`. Or you want to remove a file from the archive? If the latter, are you replacing the removed file or just leaving an empty archive? Please provide as many accurate details as you can in your question and I'll try to provide the right option(s).

Comment: FYI, to just remove a file and do nothing else, if you have archive `foo.7z` with one file `foo` you can do `7zr u foo.7z -up1q0r0x0y0z0 foo`

Comment: The input is piped so there is no file on disk to compare to.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Okay, wait, so all you want is to create an archive from stdin and on subsequent piping in from stdin you want to overwrite the contents? Because I think that's easy as long as you give a file name. Do this, whether it's the first time or Nth time: ` ...input... | 7zr a -sifoo foo.7z`  All I've done is added _foo_ after `-si` . If you confirm I'll update my answer.