# How can I combine multiple 7z archives into one?

Tags: shell-script, stdout, stdin, 7z

I'm trying to make a bash script that takes a large number of 7z archives and combines them into one archive.  Here's what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
DUMPPATH="/home/backups/dumps/"
NEWPATH=$DUMPPATH"combined/"
FILETYPE="*.7z"
DATE="$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)"
NEWNAME=$NEWPATH"AllAsOf"$DATE".7z"
for FILE in $(ls $DUMPPATH$FILETYPE)
do
        echo -n $FILE"..."
        7z e $FILE -so | 7z a -si -mx=9 $NEWNAME
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Done."
        else
                echo "Something broke"
                exit
        fi
done
```

When I ran the script I got `Error: Duplicate filename`, so I tried to run just the guts of the script: 
`7z e /home/backups/dumps/foo.7z -so | 7z a -si -mx=9 /home/backups/dumps/combined/combined.7z` . I looked inside `combined.7z`, and it contains a file called `combined`.  The reason my script wasn't working is that each file being added to `combined.7z` is being added with as the same filename.

I think I need to specify the filename inside that 7z adds each file as because it's getting its data from `stdin`.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386924/124698) that I can add the file name after the `-si` flag in 7z. I added a line to get the filename, also.  My script became:

```
#!/bin/bash
DUMPPATH="/home/backups/dumps/"
NEWPATH=$DUMPPATH"combined/"
FILETYPE="*.7z"
DATE="$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)"
NEWNAME=$NEWPATH"AllAsOf"$DATE".7z"
for FILE in $(ls $DUMPPATH$FILETYPE)
do
        echo -n $FILE"..."
        THISNAME=$(echo $FILE | sed "s|.*"$DUMPPATH"||" | sed "s/\.7z.*//")
        7z e $FILE -so | 7z a -si$THISNAME -mx=9 $NEWNAME
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Done."
        else
                echo "Something broke"
                exit
        fi
done
```

I know there's a better way to do that regex, but this works.